# send the dta afrom azure blob container to azure function using azure datafactory activity

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-factory

I have copied data to azure blob container using the copy activity.i was able to use that to trigger my azure function using Blob trigger.However my req is to call the azure function activity that can be configured in azure datafactory pipeline.to that i need to pass the blob container path so that the azure function based on the HTTP trigger can read from this path.Blob trigger works but isnt allowed.Any idea as to how to get the path of the container and pass it to the azure function activity?

Edit:-
i added this
[image]

And the output of the path in the request sent to the HTTPTrigger of azure func looks like this

[image]

This is where i need the fully formed path post the copy say **folder/myfolder/2010/10/01**
However i dont.

---

-----------------------UPDATE----------------------------------------------------
this is the sink dataset
[image]

with the connection of the dataset(sink)like this
[image]

and my copypipeline looks like this
[image]

ran the debug and the copy instead of folder/myfolder/2020/10/01 gives folder/myfolder/@variables('data')

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the description of your question, it seems you do not know the target blob path of the "Copy" activity. I guess you use pipeline parameter to input the blob path in your data factory. Something like below:

[image]

So in the HTTP trigger function request body, you just need to choose the `testPath`.

[image]

If your function request body need to be like `{"path":"xxx"}`, you can use "[concat()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-expression-language-functions#concat)" function in data factory to join the string together.

==================================**Update**=================================

[image]

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222370/discussion-on-answer-by-hury-shen-send-the-dta-afrom-azure-blob-container-to-azu).